# i am trying to install extension from magento marketplace display this error

Tags: magento-community

display this type error while install from magento marketplace

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks ike you need to do a couple of things on the server before you're able to install new extensions from the Magento marketplace.

The first error says that your cron job has not yet been configured.  Cron is basically a system that checks in with the Magento site to find out if anything needs to be done.

Cron is used to send transactional emails (this was done for performance reasons, so that the system isn't trying to send out emails during the checkout process), and also used for re-indexing producdts... and many other function.

Without cron, your Magento 2 site is not going to run very well (if at all).

Second, it sounds like the extensions that you're trying to install / run on the site don't match the version numbers for what they are dependent on.

For example, if you're trying to install an extension that is "dependent" on another extension... that extension needs to make sure that the dependency matches properly.  So if you have an extension that needs the 2.1.4 framework to run, but your site is at 2.0.4, then this is going to likely fail.

I hope this helps answer the question for you.